# Avoid code repetition in c# - by using generics?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have following code in controller code:

```
public async Task<int> PullClientsAsync()
{
    var service = new DesktopConnectorService<ClientModel>(
            new WapiRepository<ClientModel>(), new QuickBooksRepository<ClientModel>());
    var filter = new ClientSearchFilter();
    try
    {
        var items = await service.GetItemsAsync(filter);
        return items.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }
    return 0;
}

public async Task<int> PullInvoicesAsync()
{
    var service = new DesktopConnectorService<InvoiceModel>(
        new WapiRepository<InvoiceModel>(), new QuickBooksRepository<InvoiceModel>());
    var filter = new InvoicesSearchFilter();
    try
    {
        var items = await service.GetItemsAsync(filter);
        return items.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }
    return 0;
}

public async Task<int> PullPaymentsAsync()
{
    var service = new DesktopConnectorService<PaymentModel>(
        new WapiRepository<PaymentModel>(), new QuickBooksRepository<PaymentModel>());
    var filter = new PaymentSearchFilter();
    try
    {
        var items = await service.GetItemsAsync(filter);
        return items.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see it is all about three types (ClientModel, PaymentModel and Invoices model). Lots of code above is repeating.

But I believe that it could be simplified. Any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If all models and filters share a common interface / base class, you can do:

```
public async Task<int> PullAsync<TModel, TFilter>() 
                       where TModel : IModel, 
                       where TFilter : IFilter, new();
{
    var service = new DesktopConnectorService<TModel>(
                    new WapiRepository<TModel>(), new QuickBooksRepository<TModel>());
    var filter = new TFilter();
    try
    {
        var items = await service.GetItemsAsync(filter);
        return items.Count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Side note - Don't use empty catch blocks like that, they swallow exceptions, making it very difficult to diagnose problems which may occur at a later point in time. At least have a logging statement in there, or do something meaningful. Otherwise, I'd remove it.

Comment: To clarify, last Yuval's paragraph: swallowing exceptions is bad because when you do, if your program misbehaves, you do not get immediate feedback. It makes it much more difficult to find the issue when it happens, because your code is actively hiding it. If you are swallowing exceptions consistently throughout your code you are making your software an unmaintainable mess.